# how to print 19.129494 as 19.1 sec or 19 sec in python by Using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Hello guys i have program where i'm getting a total time taken by the program to complete the operation for that code is:

```
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()
.........................
.........................
print("Total Time Taken to uploading file- " + format(datetime.now() - startTime))
```

this will print the output like this:**Total Time Taken to uploading file-0:00:19.129494**
but i want to split the code on the basis of hr,min,sec so for that i have written a code like:

```
arr=format(datetime.now() - startTime).split(":")
    Hour= int(arr[0])
    MIN= int(arr[1])
    time1= arr[2].split(".")
    Sec = int(time1[0])
    MilliSec = int(time1[1])
    list=[]
    if Hour != 0:
        list.append(arr[0])
        list.append("HOUR")
        print(arr[0],"HH")
    if MIN != 0:
        list.append(arr[1])
        list.append("MINNUTE")
        print(arr[1],"MIN")
    if Sec != 0:
        list.append(time1[0])
        list.append("SECOND")
        print(arr[2],"SEC")
    if MilliSec != 0:
        list.append(time1[1])
        list.append("MilliSecond")
        print(arr[2],"MilliSec")
```

After this i got an output like:**['19','second','129494','Millisecond']**
I know this is not a good program but anyway i need to print the output
**The thing i'm not able to print is:** It should show like this total time taken is 19.1 second or 19 sec i want remove list and remove the millisec(129494) or print only till 2 or 1 decimal places for the millisec please help me to get it thnx.....

Comment: Do you not realize that you can convert milliseconds to seconds by dividing by 1000? Also it seems you might be talking about microseconds not milliseconds, so you'd need to divide by 1000000.

Comment: @MarkRansom let me try that

Comment: @MarkRansom and how to remove that list(['19','second','129494','Millisecond'] ) while printing the output like this 19 second

Comment: @rahulsingh `' '.join(lst)`  fyi don't use `list` as a variable name.  it's a pre-defined class.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 where should i add that i my code please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Just print the `.seconds` attribute of the `datetime.timedelta` object.

I.e.

```
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()
#... some more code
print('time taken', (datetime.now() - startTime).seconds)
```

Comment: Well if your code is taking less than a second, then it would! Throw a `time.sleep(3)` in place of the `#... some more code` and see if then you get a result of `3` seconds.